# Different coloured repeating bullet points

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a website for a client in Wordpress and I'm looking to change the standard black bullet points to be different colours. In their logo, they have 5 different shades of pink circles so they would like their bullet points to replicate this. I.e. the first 5 bullet points to be the 5 shades of pink, then repeat. How can I achieve this across the website?

Thanks,
Becky

Comment: You can achieve what you want. Only you need to try something. This question should be closed as offtopic or you need to edit the post with a correct question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try using `nth-of-type` or `nth-child`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a pattern [nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) is the way to go, it lets you pick how many should be skipped and a starting point.

```css
ul>li:nth-child(5n - 4) {
  color: red
}
ul>li:nth-child(5n - 3) {
  color: #ff0
}
ul>li:nth-child(5n - 2) {
  color: pink
}
ul>li:nth-child(5n - 1) {
  color: green
}
ul>li:nth-child(5n) {
  color: purple
}
ul>li>span {
  color: #000
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>List Item 1</span>
  </li>
  <li><span>List Item 2</span>
  </li>
  <li><span>List Item 3</span>
  </li>
  <li><span>List Item 4</span>
  </li>
  <li><span>List Item 5</span>
  </li>
  <li><span>List Item 6</span>
  </li>
  <li><span>List Item 7</span>
  </li>
  <li><span>List Item 8</span>
  </li>
  <li><span>List Item 9</span>
  </li>
  <li><span>List Item 10</span>
  </li>
  <li><span>List Item 11</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> I can list a rainbow, list a rainbow too.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks, this works great! However, it changes the colour of the text too. How can I use this to just change the colour of the bullet points and leave the text as black?

Comment: The reason the text is in a span is so ul>li>span {color: #000} makes it black again.

Answer (score 0):

ok first make css and save it to css editor of wordpress

Like

```css
ul {  list-style: none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.lired:before {
    content: "• ";
    color: red;            /* For Red*/
}

.lipink:before {
    content: "• ";
    color: pink;            /* For pink*/
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="lipink">ddwdw</li>
<li class="lired">ddwdw</li>

</ul>
```